# Implementing relatively sized buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I'm trying to make 4 buttons that each take up 1/4 of the screen. However when I create the buttons as shown below, they are all in the same position. I'm not sure how this is possible since I have set their origins in a all different places. Could someone explain why this is happening and offer a solution?

Edit: I removed auto-layout and did not fix the problem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.sequence = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    float sizeWidth = [self view].bounds.size.width/2;
    float sizeHeight = [self view].bounds.size.height/2;
    CGPoint origin = [self view].bounds.origin;
    // Configure button sizes
    CGRect topLeft = CGRectMake(origin.x/2, origin.y/2, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    _zeroButton.frame = topLeft;
    CGRect topRight = CGRectMake(origin.x * 3/2, origin.y/2, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    _oneButton.frame = topRight;
    CGRect bottomLeft = CGRectMake(origin.x/2, origin.y * 3/2, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    _twoButton.frame = bottomLeft;
    CGRect bottomRight = CGRectMake(origin.x * 3/2, origin.y * 3/2, sizeWidth, sizeHeight);
    _threeButton.frame = bottomRight;

}
```

Comment: try check orign like this: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(origin)); after CGPoint origin =... and you will understand your mistake.

Comment: Yeah, @stosha's right. I'd tell you your mistake, but it's best you see it for yourself.

Comment: Is origin {0,0}? If so, then your operations will always end up with {0,0}.

Comment: @blzn And in general `bounds` (unlike frame) will always return origin {0,0}. In this case though, both the view's bounds and frame are at {0, 0}. You're probably going to want to use the screen height and width to get the origin results you want.

Answer (score 0):

All of your rectangles are at origin 0,0 because you are using (only) multiplication and division  operations on them...
You should perhaps look at CGRectOffset()..
eg.

```
CGRect rct = self.view.bounds;
rct.size.width /= 2.0;
rct.size.height /= 2.0;

UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:rct]; //top left
  //  add target, addToView etc..

UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectOffset(rct, rct.size.width, 0.0) ];
  // etc..

UIButton *button3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectOffset(rct, 0.0, rct.size.height) ];
  //etc
UIButton *button4 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectOffset(rct, rct.size.width, rct.size.height) ];
 //etc
```